# How to build a query with variable number of match() clauses using the ElasticSearch Java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I want to retrieve documents based on a combination of 3 field values:

- canonicalForm
- grammar
- meaning

Here is how I do it now.

```
String canonicalForm = "tut";
String grammar = "verb";
String meaning = "to land";

BoolQuery bool = BoolQuery.of(q -> q
            .must(m -> m
                .match(mt -> mt
                    .field("descr.canonicalForm")
                        .query(canonicalForm)
                    )
            )
            .must(m -> m
                .match(mt -> mt
                    .field("descr.grammar")
                        .query(grammar)
                    )
            )
            .must(m -> m
                .match(mt -> mt
                    .field("descr.meaning")
                        .query(meaning)
                    )
            )
        );
```

This works as long as I provide a value for all three fields. But sometimes I want to search using only 1 or two of the fields.

I tried setting the "absent" field values to null, but that raises an exception.

I also tried setting the "absent" value to the empty string but that always returns 0 hits.

Another solution would be to only add a match() clause for a field if the provided value is not null, but I can't figure out how to insert this kind of conditionals in the fluent DSL builder pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new code java.

```
 var map = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
      put("descr.canonicalForm", "tut");
      put("descr.grammar", "verb");
      put("descr.meaning", "");
    }};

    var queries = new ArrayList<Query>();

    map.forEach((field, entry) -> {
      if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(entry)) {
        queries.add(MatchQuery.of(m -> m.field(field).query(entry))._toQuery());
      }
    });

    var boolQuery = BoolQuery.of(bq -> bq.must(queries));

    SearchRequest sr = SearchRequest.of(s -> s
        .index("morphemes")
        .query(q -> q.bool(boolQuery)
        )
    );
```

Comment: My understanding is that should() is a boolean OR. So the above could return results that only match one of the three conditions. What I want is a boolean AND (i.e. must) but with a variable number of conditions.

Comment: I just noticed the minimumShouldMatch() in your suggestion. If I understand, this guarantees that at least one of the 3 matches (any of them) will be met. But this is not enough for my needs because I want SPECIFIC matches to be met. For example, if grammar is the only non-null value, then I want that value to match. If grammar and meaning are non-null, I want those two to match.

Comment: I updated my answer. For each condition with a null variable there is a combination of matches. Maybe that's what you're looking for.

Comment: That still would not work. In my index, all the fields are always defined, so your example above would always return an empty list. When the input value of a field is null, it does not mean that I want docs for which that field is null. It means that I don't care what the value of that field is.

Comment: if the input value is null, you must ignore it and build the query only with non-null values.

Comment: Yes, that's my question. What's the easiest and most fluent way of building a query that will only check for input fields whose values are not null.

Comment: That's not possible, Elasticsearch doesn't do that and shouldn't be responsible. If your entries are null remove them and create a new query for each situation you want.

Comment: Here's the thing. I receive those three field values from the UI. I now need to compose a query that will match the subset of those fields (i.e. the ones for which I received a non-null value). Surely there is a fluent way of doing that? See the answer I created for my own question which shows one way to do that, but it's awkward as heck. Can you suggest a more fluent way to do it? Thx.

Comment: Here is another way to think about this. Suppose I receive an argument 'Map<String,String> fieldsToMatch'  where the keys are the names of fields and the values are the values of the fields. The map may contain an arbitrary number of fields. How Would I compose a query that matches all those fields against the values provided in the map?

Comment: what you do is exactly what I said, check if the entry is null, if not, create the match clause.
There are better ways to do this than the code you posted. I'm going to make an example that will create the matches only when the input is not null, ok?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250979/discussion-between-rabbitbr-and-alain-desilets).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but it's awkward as hell. If someone has a more fluent solution to suggest, please let me know.

The solution I came up with is to:

- Create the query as a JSONObject
- Transform that JSONObject to an InputStream
- Feed that InputStream to .query(q -> q.withJson()) method

Here is an example below:

```
        // Say we have these input field values
        String canonicalForm = "tut";
        String grammar = "verb";
        String meaning = null; // This means we don't want to query on field 'meaning'

        // Build a JSONArray that will contain the "match" criteria for the non-null
        // input field values
        //
        JSONArray mustArr = new JSONArray();
        if (canonicalForm != null) {
            mustArr.put(new JSONObject()
                .put("match", new JSONObject()
                    .put("descr.canonicalForm", new JSONObject()
                        .put("query", canonicalForm)
                    )
                )
            );
        }
        if (grammar != null) {
            mustArr.put(new JSONObject()
                .put("match", new JSONObject()
                    .put("descr.grammar", new JSONObject()
                        .put("query", grammar)
                    )
                )
            );
        }
        if (meaning != null) {
            mustArr.put(new JSONObject()
                .put("match", new JSONObject()
                    .put("descr.meaning", new JSONObject()
                        .put("query", meaning)
                    )
                )
            );
        }

        // Build a "bool" query object, feeding it the "must" array.
        JSONObject queryJObj = new JSONObject()
            .put("bool", new JSONObject()
                .put("must", mustArr)
            )
        ;

        // Convert the "query" object to an InputStream
        String queryJsonStr = queryJObj.toString();
        InputStream queryIS = new ByteArrayInputStream(queryJsonStr.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        SearchRequest sr = SearchRequest.of(s -> s
            .index("morphemes")
            .query(q -> q
                    .withJson(queryIS)
            )
        );
```